# Issues moving from RestTemplate to WebClient (Spring Boot 2.0.0.M3)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

Been stumped for a while on this one!

Moving from a regular MVC project to a reactive one, and am working with Spring Boot (new version 2.0.0.M3).

I've had zero issues with the library as a whole until this particular prblem arose.

While working with WebClient, I have a request that isn't working. It worked just fine previously with RestTemplate:

```
rt.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
headers.add("Authorization", "Basic REDACTED");

HttpEntity<OtherApiRequest> entity = 
new HttpEntity<OtherApiRequest>(CrawlRequestBuilder.buildCrawlRequest(req), headers);

ResponseEntity<Void> response = rt.postForEntity("https://other_api/path", 
    entity, 
    Void.class);

System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
```

My WebClient code:

```
client
  .post()
  .uri("https://other_api/path")
  .header("Authorization", "Basic REDACTED")
  .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  .body(Mono.just(req), OtherApiRequest.class)
  .exchange()
  .then(res -> System.out.println(res.getStatusCode()));
```

I've also tried generating the body first:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String body = mapper.writeValueAsString(
client
  .post()
  .uri("https://other_api/path")
  .header("Authorization", "Basic REDACTED")
  .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  .body(body, String.class)
  .exchange()
  .then(res -> System.out.println(res.getStatusCode()));
```

Is there anything here that stands out as wrong? I can't see any issues between the two that would cause the second one to fail...

Edit:
The RestTemplate provides a response of 204. The WebClient provides a response of 400, saying the body is invalid JSON. Using the second example for WebClient above, I can print the `body` variable and see it is proper JSON.

Edit2: The POJO class I am serializing:

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
public class OtherApiRequest {
    private String app;
    private String urllist;
    private int maxDepth;
    private int maxUrls;

   public OtherApiRequest(String app, String urllist, int maxDepth, int maxUrls) {
        this.app = app;
        this.urllist = urllist;
        this.maxDepth = maxDepth;
        this.maxUrls = maxUrls;
    }

   public String getApp() {
        return app;
    }

   public String getUrllist() {
        return urllist;
    }

   public int getMaxDepth() {
        return maxDepth;
    }

   public int getMaxUrls() {
        return maxUrls;
    }

   public String toString() {
        return "OtherApiRequest: {" +
            "app: " + app + "," +
            "urllist: " + urllist + "," +
            "max_depth: " + maxDepth + "," +
            "max_urls: " + maxUrls +
            "}";
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What behaviour are you seeing?

Comment: My bad! I get 204 for a regular response with the RestTemplate, but using the WebClient I get a 400 response, saying the body is not proper JSON. Using the second WebClient example above I printed the body I created and it is properly formatted when I print out the `body` variable. I'll edit the request above to reflect this.

Comment: can you try this: `.body(BodyInserters.fromPublisher(Mono.just("data")), String.class);` or `.body(BodyInserters.fromObject("data"));` with the serialized json string?

Comment: Both of those suggestions provide the same 400 response, with the same message.

Comment: hmm, can you show the JSON-String that you set as body?

Comment: `{"app":"default_app","urllist":"test_url_list","max_depth":0,"max_urls":1}` and the POJO class used to create this is added to the question above.

Comment: @chrisor there is some weird thing with the string you posted, there is an invalid character after `"max_depth":0‌​`. If I put your string into a JSON-validator, it says: Unexpected token ‌ at position 59.

Comment: @JohnnyAW I think that is SO or something; when I copy/paste from the server output into a validator there aren't illegal characters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing Content-Length header sending POST request with WebClient (SpringBoot 2.0.2.RELEASE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50492890/missing-content-length-header-sending-post-request-with-webclient-springboot-2)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

See better answers here

[Missing Content-Length header sending POST request with WebClient (SpringBoot 2.0.2.RELEASE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50492890/missing-content-length-header-sending-post-request-with-webclient-springboot-2#50504139)

Bug Report

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21085

Fixed in 2.2

When I experienced "Invalid JSON Response" I looked at the WebClient Request via netcat and found out, that the actual payload, in this example `3.16` was enclosed in some kind of content information:

```
$ netcat -l 6500
PUT /value HTTP/1.1
user-agent: ReactorNetty/0.7.5.RELEASE
transfer-encoding: chunked
host: localhost:6500
accept-encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json

4
3.16
0
```

After I added `contentLength()` to the builder the preceeding 4 and the trailing 0 vanished.