# Spring WebClient POST and Content Length Header for application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webclient

I am using Spring WebClient and Spring Boot 2.3.5.RELEASE to POST a request to a site that wants a Content Type of application/x-www-form-urlencoded.  It keeps failing because the Content-Length header is not set.  I can set that in the code, but I'm not sure how to compute the Content-Length when the Content-Type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded.  The URL I am accessing is a legacy site.  I saw this post [Missing Content-Length header sending POST request with WebClient (SpringBoot 2.0.2.RELEASE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50492890/missing-content-length-header-sending-post-request-with-webclient-springboot-2) but it doesn't address the issue for Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

I executed the same request in Postman, and it works fine.  In Postman if I remove the Content-Length header I get the same error I see in the code.

Please advise how to compute the Content-Length.  Thank you.

Here is a snippet.

```
final MultiValueMap<String, String> formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    formData.add("key 1, "value 1");
    formData.add("key 2, "value 2");
    formData.add("key 3, "value 3");
    formData.add("key 4, "value 4");

ResponseEntity<String>  resp = webClient
   .post()
   .uri("https://myurl")
   .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
   .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH,
        String.valueOf(???))
   .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData(formData))
   .exchange()
   .flatMap(response -> response.toEntity(String.class))
   .block();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a solution.  Turns out that this had nothing to do with Content-Length.  I decided to try accessing the same REST endpoint with RestTemplate.  I got an identical error where the target endpoint complained about missing parameters.  Yet, when I accessed it with Postman or curl it worked perfectly fine.

Instead of using `BodyInserters.fromFormData` with a MultiValueMap, I used `BodyInserters.fromValue(bodyData)`.  For the body data I built a String of values similar to what curl used.

`grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=123&client_secret=456&scope=myScope`

This issue is perhaps limited to the host serving this API(not a public one), but I found it interesting that RestTemplate and WebClient both failed with a standard approach for `x-www-form-urlencoded`, while Postman and curl worked just fine.