# Content-Length header sending POST request with WebClient for multipart/form-data

Tags: java, spring, spring-webclient

I'm trying to send POST multipart request using WebClient (spring-web 5.2.9.RELEASE), but it is missing "Content-Length" header required by the API.

Is it possible to configure WebClient to include "Content-Length" header for MultipartHttpMessageWriter which using to write request with multipart/form-data media type?

I'm sending request in this way:

```
webClient.post().body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData((MultiValueMap<String, HttpEntity<String>>)request)).exchange();
```

Comment: Check if it answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50492890/missing-content-length-header-sending-post-request-with-webclient-springboot-2

Comment: I saw, but it seems, that for MultiValueMap this way to calculate Content-Length doesn't work :(

Answer (score 3):

Create `ExchangeFilterFunction` like this one https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/26489#issuecomment-896182570 and register it, for example

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
                .filter(new MultipartExchangeFilterFunction())
                ...
                .build();
```

Where `MultipartExchangeFilterFunction` implements `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFilterFunction`, calculates body length and creates the `Content-Length` header.